# CPack CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_RELEASE cannot be set to 0

Tags: cmake, rpm, cpack

I need to create a RPM of my software expecting the following output: <my_sw_name>-<version>-<release>.rpm.

The default for <release> shall be 0.

In my CMakeLists.txt I am using the following command:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
...
set(SW_RELEASE 0)
set(CPACK_GENERATOR "RPM")
set(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_RELEASE ${SW_RELEASE})
set(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_RELEASE_DIST OFF)
set(CPACK_RPM_FILE_NAME "RPM-DEFAULT")
...
```

Nevertheless, the generated RPM filename is <my_sw_name>-<version>-**1**.rpm, and the `Release:` field in the RPM file is set to `1`.

Is this a bug in CPack or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To any future users who aren't aware, [It's conventional to start the release number for RPM packages at `1` and not at `0`](https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/#preamble-items). And here's [a link to the CPackRPM docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/rpm.html) in case anyone needs it.

Reading through [`:/Modules/Internal/CPack/CPackRPM.cmake`](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/v3.24.1/Modules/Internal/CPack/CPackRPM.cmake#L965) for CMake version 3.24.1, I think the culprit is the following code at line 965 inside the function `cpack_rpm_generate_package`:

```
  if(NOT CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_RELEASE)
    set(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_RELEASE "1")
  endif()
```

The string `0` in CMake is falsy. Ex,

```
if(NOT 0)
  message("zero is falsy") # this will be reached and printed
endif()
```

Ie. your `0` causes the expression `NOT CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_RELEASE` to evaluate to `FALSE`, and then your `0` gets clobbered to a `1`.

If you want the value `0` to be supported, you could file [an issue on the CMake gitlab repo](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues) requesting it. It would probably look like changing it to this:

```
  if(NOT DEFINED CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_RELEASE)
    set(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_RELEASE "1")
  endif()
```

If this is truly the cause and you do file an issue to kitware, please either add a link to it as a comment under this answer, or to the end of the body of your question so future readers can find it.